# RemoteInterpreterの設定ができない。

Tags: python

Docekr内のPython環境に合わせたいのですが、
設定が上手くいきません。

解決策が見つからないので、アドバイスをいただけますでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下は、表示されている警告です。

```
    Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter
        failed to run generator3.py for docker-compose://[D:\Project\Docker\Web\docker-compose.yml]:django/python, exit code 1, stderr: 
        -----
        Pulling pycharm_helpers (pycharm_helpers:PY-181.5087.37)...
        pull access denied for pycharm_helpers, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
        -----
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト：https://stackoverflow.com/q/51421689/ . Pycharm の話なんですね

Comment: そうです。Pychamのタグが無かったもので…